# display web page source in android app

Tags: java, android

This is my first project in android java. I am trying to get a page source and display it. (I will use this with json later.) I followed a tutorial on lynda.com but I can't get this to work. there is a edittext, textview, and a button in this app. the user enter a url and press the button and the app adds the source to the page. When I click the button nothing happen. how can I fix this.
Note i have the internet permission added already.

**Main.java**

```
package com.example.news;

import java.io.BufferedReader;
import java.io.InputStreamReader;
import java.net.URL;
import java.net.URLConnection;

import android.os.Bundle;
import android.app.Activity;
import android.view.View;
import android.view.View.OnClickListener;
import android.widget.Button;
import android.widget.EditText;
import android.widget.TextView;

public class Main extends Activity {

    @Override
    public void onCreate(Bundle savedInstanceState) {
        super.onCreate(savedInstanceState);
        setContentView(R.layout.main);

        final EditText et = (EditText) findViewById(R.id.editText1);
        final Button b = (Button) findViewById(R.id.button1);
        final TextView tv = (TextView) findViewById(R.id.textView1);


        b.setOnClickListener(new OnClickListener() {

            @Override
            public void onClick(View v) {
                try{
                    URL url = null;
                    url = new URL(et.getText().toString());
                    URLConnection conn = url.openConnection();
                    BufferedReader reader = new BufferedReader(new InputStreamReader(conn.getInputStream()));
                    String line = "";
                    while((line = reader.readLine()) != null){
                        tv.append(line);
                    }
                }catch(Exception e){

                }

            }
        });

    }


}
```

This is my manifest file

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="utf-8"?>
<manifest xmlns:android="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android"
    package="com.example.news"
    android:versionCode="1"
    android:versionName="1.0" >

    <uses-sdk
        android:minSdkVersion="7"
        android:targetSdkVersion="18" />
    <uses-permission android:name="android.permission.INTERNET"/>

    <application
        android:allowBackup="true"
        android:icon="@drawable/ic_launcher"
        android:label="@string/app_name"
        android:theme="@style/AppTheme" >
        <activity
            android:name="com.example.news.Main"
            android:label="@string/app_name" >
            <intent-filter>
                <action android:name="android.intent.action.MAIN" />

                <category android:name="android.intent.category.LAUNCHER" />
            </intent-filter>
        </activity>
    </application>

</manifest>
```

I got this error: `android.os.NetworkOnMainThreadException`

Comment: Empty `catch` block, disaster!!!! Add `stacktrace` in your `Exception` block, it  may reveal some failures.

Comment: I have Log.e("Log_tag", "Error converting result"+e.toString());
  e.printStackTrace();

Comment: May be just try debugging line by line and, see whether you get the source correctly

Comment: when I click I get this error in catLog android.os.NetworkOnMainThreadException

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You are using the Internet on Main Thread.
You should use the code in doInBackground().

```
class Abc extends ASyncTask<String, String, String>
{
public String doInBackground(String... params)
 {
  URL url = null;
                url = new URL(et.getText().toString());
                URLConnection conn = url.openConnection();
                BufferedReader reader = new BufferedReader(new InputStreamReader(conn.getInputStream()));
                String line = "";
                while((line = reader.readLine()) != null){
                    tv.append(line);
 }
}
```

And in OnClick
       new Abc.execute();